# How to Throw Error with Excel Prompt in VBA

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-addins, vba

I have some code which looks for a value with a given sheet name in two separate workbooks.

What I want to do is when the first workbook does not have the sheet, instead of the following prompt coming up, it cancels/throws an error and using the error handling goes to the second spreadsheet. How do I do this?

[image: Sheet Select Prompt]

Currently I am using this code to achieve this:

```
fFormString1 = "'" & wkBookRef1 & firstShtName & "'!$L$6/1000"
fFormString2 = "'" & wkBookRef2 & firstShtName & "'!$L$6/1000"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Does nothing to the prompt
On Error GoTo tryTwo 'Following only throws error when prompt is canceled
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Place").Range("E53").Formula = "=" & fFormString1
    GoTo endTen

tryTwo:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Place").Range("E53").Formula = "=IFERROR(" & fFormString2 & ","""")"
    On Error Resume Next
endTen:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Does nothing to the prompt
```

Note: I wish to do this with the spreadsheet closed ideally. Or visually not present to improve speed and smoothness of operation for my client.

Comment: Do you have some code for us to look at?

Comment: @Comintern Code added above, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from Thomas' answer (full credit is due). However it seems that this didn't work for you.

Use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` but ascribe the value to the variable `val`. Then check if this is the error you are looking for `Error(2023)`.

Please find the code below:

```
'Check if the sheet exists in the workbook, used to check which forecast file one should look in
Function ExtSheetExists(formString) As Boolean 'Form string is a formula string with both the worksheet and the workbook
    Dim val As Variant
    'Tries to execute formula and throws error if it doesn't exist
    On Error Resume Next
    val = ExecuteExcel4Macro(formString)
    ExtSheetExists = (val <> Error(2023)) 'Returns False if the sheet does not exist based on Error 2023
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteExcel4Macro` will return a value from a closed workbook.  If the worksheet doesn't exist it will throw an error `1004 'A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references.`

`ExternalWorksheetExists` uses this to test it the worksheet exist.

[image]

```
Function ExternalWorksheetExists(FilePath As String, FileName As String, WorksheetName As String) As Boolean

    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

    On Error Resume Next
    Call ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & FilePath & "[" & FileName & "]" & WorksheetName & "'!R3C3")
    ExternalWorksheetExists = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

When using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`, all references must be given as R1C1 strings.  Here is an example of a valid string:

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\Users\tinzina\Documents\[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1'!R6C12")
```

Comment: it appears that the ExecuteExcel4Macro always returns an error. And yes I have checked the filepath countless times. The Error always seems to return as the non-zero 1004

Comment: I've copy pasted the reference from the input string and it works perfectly. I'm not using the relative RC referencing though. But when I do it always returns `True`. If I use the non-RC it always returns `False`

Comment: I give an example of a valid string in my updated answer.  `ExecuteExcel4Macro` only accepts RC strings. I don't understand why it would always return true when using a RC string.  `ExecuteExcel4Macro` will throw an error if the worksheet doesn't exist.

Comment: No it doesn't matter.   `ExecuteExcel4Macro` will execute a worksheet function,   execute a macro or return a range value from a closed or open workbook.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I found a work-around which has `val =`  instead of `Call` and that returns either the value of the cell or an error. Then I just have `val <> Error(2023)` as the logical condition. Shall I edit to reflect this?

Comment: Obviously heavily borrowed from your solution. Not sure why my machine operates differently. Accept the edit and I'll accept the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Did you actually run this?

Comment: Yes, I did.  It's tricky to get ExecuteExcel4Macro's parameter right.  The image of the immediate window shows my tests are I finished debugging `ExternalWorksheetExists`.   I used `ExternalWorksheetExists(ThisWorkbook.Path,ThisWorkbook.Name,Worksheets(1).name)` to test True (that the worksheet actually exists) and `ExternalWorksheetExists(ThisWorkbook.Path,ThisWorkbook.Name,"Sheet50")` to test False  (that the worksheet doesn't exists - because there is no `Sheet50`).

Comment: If you run the incorrect sheet reference manually in a sheet are you prompted for a select worksheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121795/discussion-between-thomas-inzina-and-aer).